# WAMP Node.js server disappears after several seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a beginner using node.js so I have some errors and some questions please.

First: I using this code to make the server

```js
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   // Send the HTTP header 
   // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
   // Content Type: text/plain
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   // Send the response body as "Hello World"
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080);
// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

When I try to http://127.0.0.1:8080 I get this error in console log

> ```
> GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
> ```

My server.js is inside www of the wamp directly.

Comment: Wamp is occupying that port probably, try switching to another port for your node server and it should work

Comment: node.js creates its own server; you don't need WAMP. You run your server by entering `node server.js` into a terminal while in the folder containing the file.

Comment: Hello bro, i know Node.js creates it's own server. but i do not need nodeJs with all thing. i'm beginner in node.js i want just do some easy things.

So should i put the server.js inside my project to detect the directory of the server connection.

Comment: And about the error i trying using many ports, but not working i get this error too.

Comment: The code you have works absolutely fine for me, provided I run it from a terminal by typing `node server.js`. The terminal will say `Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/` and keep running until I press Ctrl+C. Visiting `localhost:8080` in a browser shows "Hello World", as expected. If you think you are smarter than me and don't need node to run that code, why are you posting a question on stack overflow?

Comment: Bro Chris, Is not working for me as i say i'm a beginner in node.js i do not know what's the problem! 
Please let me know what the problem is.

Comment: 1. if you want to use node, you don't need WAMP or its www folder. 2. what you need is to install node.js, then run your script by typing `node [filename]` into a terminal. I basically already told you this, twice.

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear: WAMP is a **PHP** server. To use it, put `<?php echo "Hello World";` in a file, and save it as `index.php` in your www folder. Then go to `http://localhost`

Comment: I will test it in nodeJs command prompt.
i will give you the result.

Comment: Now in windows command prompt.
it's working nice! but not working when trying with http://127.0.0.1:8080/

Comment: One of these was the problem
-After update node.js. to last version.
-open 8080 port in firewall

I do not know which of these resolved my problem exactly, Any way thanks to all.